# Error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module weak

Tags: node.js, npm

I had below `npm` and `node` versions in our docker container along with`Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` as a base image. Here everything was working.

```
$ npm --version
6.13.4

$ node --version
v8.17.0
```

Today i have changed the docker image to `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` and upgraded `npm` and `node` versions.

```
$ npm --version
8.1.2

$ node --version
v16.13.1
```

With these versions, i have executed below commands.

```
npm install
npm cache clean --force
```

Now my application giving below errors.

```
2022-01-06 02:50:21.702 - error: agent_64: "Error: Cannot find module 'weak'\n" +
  'Require stack:\n' +
  '- /mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js\n' +
  '- /mlbs/core/rpc.js\n' +
  '- /mlbs/core/base-server.js\n' +
  '- /mlbs/core/mlbs.js\n' +
  '- /mlbs/plugins/mlbs.server.agent/bin/agent.js\n' +
  '    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)\n' +
  '    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)\n' +
  '    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)\n' +
  '    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)\n' +
  '    at new D (/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js:28:20)\n' +
  '    at module.exports (/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js:8:12)\n' +
  '    at Rpc.createStream (/mlbs/core/rpc.js:151:20)\n' +
  '    at Server.onConnection (/mlbs/core/base-server.js:608:21)\n' +
  '    at Server.emit (node:events:390:28)\n' +
  '    at Server.emit (node:domain:475:12)'
2022-01-06 02:50:21.708 - error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'weak'
Require stack:
- /mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js
- /mlbs/core/rpc.js
- /mlbs/core/base-server.js
- /mlbs/core/mlbs.js
- /mlbs/plugins/mlbs.server.agent/bin/agent.js date=Thu Jan 06 2022 02:50:21 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time), pid=1, uid=0, gid=0, cwd=/, execPath=/usr/bin/node, version=v16.13.1, argv=[/usr/bin/node, /mlbs/plugins/mlbs.server.agent/bin/agent.js, start, -i, agent_64, -p, 32000], rss=69791744, heapTotal=26386432, heapUsed=24357592, external=18881423, arrayBuffers=17940662, loadavg=[0.23, 0.34, 0.39], uptime=43161.61, trace=[column=15, file=node:internal/modules/cjs/loader, function=Module._resolveFilename, line=933, method=_resolveFilename, native=false, column=27, file=node:internal/modules/cjs/loader, function=Module._load, line=778, method=_load, native=false, column=19, file=node:internal/modules/cjs/loader, function=Module.require, line=1005, method=require, native=false, column=18, file=node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers, function=require, line=102, method=null, native=false, column=20, file=/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js, function=new D, line=28, method=null, native=false, column=12, file=/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js, function=module.exports, line=8, method=exports, native=false, column=20, file=/mlbs/core/rpc.js, function=Rpc.createStream, line=151, method=createStream, native=false, column=21, file=/mlbs/core/base-server.js, function=Server.onConnection, line=608, method=onConnection, native=false, column=28, file=node:events, function=Server.emit, line=390, method=emit, native=false, column=12, file=node:domain, function=Server.emit, line=475, method=emit, native=false], stack=[Error: Cannot find module 'weak', Require stack:, - /mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js, - /mlbs/core/rpc.js, - /mlbs/core/base-server.js, - /mlbs/core/mlbs.js, - /mlbs/plugins/mlbs.server.agent/bin/agent.js,     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15),     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27),     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19),     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18),     at new D (/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js:28:20),     at module.exports (/mlbs/node_modules/dnode/index.js:8:12),     at Rpc.createStream (/mlbs/core/rpc.js:151:20),     at Server.onConnection (/mlbs/core/base-server.js:608:21),     at Server.emit (node:events:390:28),     at Server.emit (node:domain:475:12)]
```

I searched for the error but could not understand the solutions. I'll be very thankful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: As a good rule of thumb, try an entire update with linux; fresh installs may not carry latest files/etc. But with your error message, why not try npm install weak? Can't say that's the solution but a module missing needs install so try updating OS, NPM and then install missing module.

Comment: If this module is not needed, ensure your package.json/etc is not including bad packages you don't require, in other words reset those files, delete them and go off what project requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by downgrading `npm to 6.14.12` and `node to v10.24.1` versions.